# (Discord.js v12) Mention Arguments?

Tags: discord.js

I tried to make a command with arguments and mentions. What I do is, I want to make mention the text channel as an argument. *I might explain not quite good*

### Here's the example

For example, I added command with syntax: `<prefix> <message> <#channel>` but I can't mention channel in argument [2].

What I tried:

```js
let msg = args[1];
let channel = message.mentions.channels.first(args[2]); // It quite not make any sense, right?

message.channel.send(`Message: ${msg} \nIn channel: ${channel}!`);
```

and it just crashes. A little help here!

Answer (score 1):

The reason why it is crashing is because you are using "args[]" wrong, for `let msg = args[1];` it should be set to `args[0]`. Now for the channel you can use `args[1]` or

You could try using `message.mentions` So you would do the following:

```js
let channel = message.mentions.channels.first();
```

Complete Code:

```js
let msg = args[0]; //Get the first word from the message
let announceChannel = message.mentions.channels.first(); //Get the announcement channel
message.channel.send(`Message: ${msg} \nIn channel: ${announceChannel}!`); //Let the sender know the announcement has been sent
announcementChannel.send(msg); //Send the announcement
```

Comment: Helpful, let me try it.

Comment: @JediThePro any luck ? This should be the solution.